# Postman Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost. Select a different agent

Tags: javascript, server, postman-pre-request-script

In postman web version When I send a request using get  `localhost:8080` it's just giving an arror.
`Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost. Select a different agent.`
Please help me about the situation. Is there any problem with my Vs codes ?

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

/* app.use((req, res)=> {
}); */

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("This is the home page");
});

app.get("/cats", (req, res) => {
  res.send("MEOW");
});

app.get("/dogs", (req, res) => {
  res.send("woof");
});

app.post("dogs", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Post request to /cats. This is diffrent than get");
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.send("I don't know what that path");
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 8080");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Agent runs **in the Cloud**.

"Cloud" is a buzzword loosely meaning **someone else's computer**.

Their computer cannot access services running on your **private** loopback network interface (i.e. `localhost`).

If you want the Cloud Agent to access your service then you need to host it on the public Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error, I had to download and install postman on my local machine instead of using Postman web and it worked fine.